# setTimeout function not working in ie11

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to simulate a click as soon as a specific page loads:

```
jQuery(function($){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('ul.dk_options_inner li:nth-child(2) a').trigger('click');
    }, 200);
});
```

This works in all browsers apart from IE11.
Are there any alternatives ways to adjust this to ensure compatibility with IE11?

Answer (score 1):

Better if you attach on document ready, that's the DOM is ready to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dk_options_inner li:nth-child(2) a').trigger('click');
});
```

You don't need to make an asynchronous method (like `setTimeout()`) and it works in all browsers (mobile included)